# Post multipart MockMvc Spring Tests

Tags: java, spring, junit, multipartform-data, mockmvc

I am trying to test my upload
I am usig Junit, Mockmvc and Spring

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:app-context.xml")
@WebAppConfiguration

public class UploadTest {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

Application app;
String session;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    Users.init();
    Graphs.init();
    Sessions.init();
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new Controller()).build();
    Users.setConfig("dani.pass", "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055");
    MvcResult m = mockMvc.perform(get("/logIn?name=dani&encrypted=81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055"))
            .andExpect(content().contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status", is(1)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.error", is("")))
            .andReturn();
    String content = m.getResponse().getContentAsString();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
    session=jsonObject.get("data").toString();
}

@Test
public void uploadTest1() throws Exception {
            String filePath = (new File(".")).getCanonicalFile().getCanonicalFile().getCanonicalPath()
            + "/books.ttl";

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", fis);

            HashMap<String, String> contentTypeParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
            contentTypeParams.put("name", "http://exampleTest.com/ng"+Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            contentTypeParams.put("session", session);
            MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("multipart", "form-data", contentTypeParams);
            mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/upload")
                    .file(multipartFile)
                    .param("name", "http://exampleTest.com/ng"+Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .param("session", session))
                    .andExpect(content().contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status", is(1)))
                    .andReturn();
}
}
```

Could you help me?

Error Stack Trace:

> [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@361cb7a1]
>   to prepare test instance [endpoint.security.tests.UploadTest@6f7918f0]
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'endpoint.security.tests.UploadTest':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationContext
>   endpoint.security.tests.UploadTest.wac; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationContext] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   [.cp/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationContext
>   endpoint.security.tests.UploadTest.wac; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationContext] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:

Answer (score 0):

From the error stacktrace, looks like `WebApplicationContext` is imported from wrong package `com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application`.

It should be `org.springframework.web.context`

Answer (score 0):

@Mithun has got it right. You have wrong package import for `WebApplicationContext`.